# Получить ветку и сделать merge

Tags: git, github

я клонировал репозиторий. клонировалась ветка **master**. там еще есть ветка **edit**.

как мне получить эту ветку, сделать **merge** с **master**, и потом отправить всё в основной репозиторий?

Answer (score 1):

если меняли умолчальное имя удалённого репозитория — *origin*, то подставьте своё. влить в текущую ветку (*master*) коммиты из ветки *edit* удалённого репозитория *origin*:

```
$ git merge origin/edit
```

после внесения всех, возможно необходимых, правок (после которых потребуется выполнить `git commit`), отправить изменения из текущей ветки (*master*) в назначенную для *push-а* ветку в удалённом репозитории можно так:

```
$ git push
```

если эту команду собираетесь выполнить первый раз после клонирования, то потребуется назначить ветку для *push-а* в удалённом репозитории. команда для отправки будет выглядеть так:

```
$ git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я всё правильно понял, то так:

```
git fetch
git checkout -b edit
```

Редактируете всё в ветке **edit**, коммитите изменения в неё. Когда закончите:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master:master //не забываем загрузить себе всё самое последнее из мастера, если там что-то появилось
git merge edit
```

Если повалятся конфликты, - разрешаем их и домёрдживаем.

Comment: спасибо, а как разрешить конфликты?

Comment: ну он (git) скажет в каких файлах конфликты (их может и не быть). Идёте в этот файл (или файлы), там будут куски из обоих веток (git не смог решить, из какой ветки изменения предпочтительнее), решаете, что должно быть и вписываете на это место. Вообще [вот](http://githowto.com/ru/resolving_conflicts?ref=driverlayer.com) ссылка с примерами.